# Pandas: Filling random empty rows with data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, random

I have a dataframe with several currently-empty columns. I want a fraction of these  filled with data drawn from a normal distribution, while all the rest are left blank. So, for example, if 60% of the elements should be blank, then 60% would be, while the other 40% would be filled. I already have the normal distribution, via numpy, but I'm trying to figure out how to choose random rows to fill. Currently, the only way I can think of involves FOR loops, and I would rather avoid that.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could fill empty elements of a dataframe at random? I have a bit of the code below, for the random numbers.

```
data.loc[data['ColumnA'] == 'B', 'ColumnC'] = np.random.normal(1000, 500, rowsB).astype('int64')
```

Comment: How about getting random indices of the rows, and adding data to those?

Comment: I can think of a number of ways to do what I think you're trying to do.  Problem is, I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do and I don't want to waste my time guessing.  You can improve your question by producing a [mcve].  [edit] your question accordingly and I'm sure you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

piRSquared's advice is good. We are left guessing what to solve.
Having just looked through some of the latest unanswered pandas questions there are worse.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#some redundancy here as i make an empty dataframe -pretending i start like you with a Dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(11),columns=list('abcdefg'))
num_cells = np.product(df.shape)

# make a 2-dim array with number from 1 to number cells.
arr =np.arange(1,num_cells+1)

#inplace shuffle - this is the key randomization operation
np.random.shuffle(arr)   

arr = arr.reshape(df.shape) 

#place the shuffled values, normalized to the number of cells, into my dateframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index,columns = df.columns,data=arr/np.float(num_cells))

#use applymap to set keep 40% of cells as ones, the other 60% as nan.
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0.6 else np.nan)

# now sample a full set from normal distribution
# but when multiplying the nans will cause the sampled value to nullify, whilst the multiply by 1 will retain the sample value.
df * np.random.normal(1000,500,df.shape)
```

Thus you are left with a random 40% of the cells containing a draw from your normal distribution.

[image]

If your dataframe was large you could assume the stability of the uniform rand() function. Here i didn't do that and rather determined explicitly how many cells are above and below the threshold.

Comment: Hi. I am wondering how can I use this code if I we want to fill the data frame that has different column's types like we have some columns with integer numbers and some columns with random dates? How can I fill this data frame with random dates and numbers? Thanks